# Detect temporary disk in Azure Linux VM

Tags: c, linux, azure

I am using RHEL on Azure.
I have found that, with any new Azure VM launched, I see two disks attached. 
One is root disk on which, RHEL OS is installed. 
And other is local SSD attached, but its a temporary disks.
Some part of this temporary disk is utilized for swap area.

If I am using LVM type volume manager, how can I detect the second disk is the temporary disk?
If I want to implement disk management utility in C programming language, how can I detect this temporary disk?
Is there any disk property which we can use to detect the locally attached disk?

Comment: I think this is not related to blob storage (tag remove)

Comment: why do you need this? it is always temporary in azure

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 1):

> On Linux virtual machines, the temporary disk is typically
>   **/dev/sdb** and is formatted and mounted to **/mnt** by the Azure Linux Agent.

Ref - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/about-disks-and-vhds

Answer (score 0):

> If I am using LVM type volume manager, how can I detect the second
>   disk is the temporary disk?

When you create a VM in Azure you are provided with a temporary storage automatically. The temporary disk is "**/dev/sdb1**" on a Linux VM.

If you want to configure LVM for this VM, "**/dev/sdb**" is the temporary disk, the first disk should be /dev/sdc.
More information about configure LVM for Azure Linux VM, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/configure-lvm).

Comment: Does this helpful, please let me know if you would like further assistance.